# Reading a csv file and counting a row depending on another row

Tags: python, csv, pandas, numpy, collections

I have a csv file where i need to read different columns and sum their numbers up depending on another row in the dataset.
The question is:

> How do the flight phases (ex. take off, cruise, landing..) contribute
>   to fatalities?

I have to sum up column number 23 for each different data in column 28.

I have a solution with masks and a lot of IF statements:

```
database = pd.read_csv('Aviation.csv',quotechar='"',skipinitialspace=True, delimiter=',', encoding='latin1').fillna(0)
data = database.as_matrix()

TOcounter = 0

for r in data:
    if r[28] == "TAKEOFF":
        TOcounter += r[23]
print(TOcounter)
```

This example shows the general idea of my solution. Where i would have to add a lot of if statements and counters for every different data in column 28. 
But i was wondering if there is a smarter solution to the issue.
The raw data can be found at: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/edipetres/Depressed_Year/master/Dataset_Assignment/AviationDataset.csv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like what you are trying to achieve is

```
df.groupby('Broad.Phase.of.Flight')['Total.Fatal.Injuries'].sum()
```

Comment: Exactly. I knew i was overcomplicating it. Thanks a lot for the quick reply!

Comment: Is there a way that i can select the Broad.Phase.of.Flight so i can plot the data? Right now i can only get the total.fatal.injuries out of the variable

Comment: If you want a bar plot of the categorical data, you would simply append a `.plot.bar()` to the recipe above.

Answer (score 0):

This is a quick solution, not checking for errors like if can convert a string for float. Also you should think about in searching for the right column(with text) instead of reliing on the column index (like 23 and 28)

but this should work:

```
import csv
import urllib2
import collections

url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/edipetres/Depressed_Year/master/Dataset_Assignment/AviationDataset.csv'
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
df = csv.reader(response)

d = collections.defaultdict(list)
for i,row in enumerate(df):
    key = row[28]
    if key == "" or i == 0 : continue
    val = 0 if(row[23]) ==""  else float(row[23])
    d.setdefault(key,[]).append(val)

d2 = {}
for k, v in d.iteritems(): d2[k] = sum(v)
for k, v in d2.iteritems(): print "{}:{}".format(k,v)
```

**Result:**

```
TAXI:110.0
STANDING:193.0
MANEUVERING:6430.0
DESCENT:1225.0
UNKNOWN:919.0
TAKEOFF:5267.0
LANDING:592.0
OTHER:107.0
CRUISE:6737.0
GO-AROUND:783.0
CLIMB:1906.0
APPROACH:4493.0
```